# Trigger callback from external component react testing library

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-hooks, react-testing-library

I am trying to figure out how to test callbacks that are given as props to react functional components using jest and react testing library.

Example scenario: I am testing a component that renders a modal. When a user clicks the 'Close' button on the modal, the parent component hides the modal. So logic is this:

```
 const ParentComp = () => {
  const [openModal, setOpenModal] = useState(false);
  return (
   <>
     <MyModal showModal={openModal} onClose={() => setOpenModal(false)} />
     <button data-testid="open-modal-button" onClick={()=> setOpenModal(true)}>Test</button>
  </>
 }

const MyModal = ({showModal, onClose}) => {
  return (
   {showModal && <>
     <div>This is a modal</div>
     <button data-testid="close-modal-button" onClick={onClose}>Close</button>
  </>
  }
 }
```

I am mocking the modal in my tests for the parent component as I dont want to rely on the actual modal component. With react testing library, how do I trigger the onClose in my parent component so I can test the setOpenModal(false)?

```
jest.mock('../MyModal');
beforeEach(() => {
  MyModal.mockImplementation(() => <div data-testid="my-modal" />);
});

it('should close the modal' () => {
const { container, getByTestId } = render(
    <MyParentComp />
);
const openModalButton = getByTestId('open-modal-button');

fireEvent.click(openModalButton);
const myModal = getByTestId('my-modal');

expect(myModal).toBeDefined();

//How to test setOpenModal(false) on parent component?
```

});

Comment: I dont know if this is the proper way, but the mock implementation you create can have an `onClick` that fires the close event, and then you can `fireEvent` on it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For your example, there is actually no need to mock the `MyModal` component unless the `MyModal` component has many external dependencies. See [testing-recipes.html#mocking-modules](https://reactjs.org/docs/testing-recipes.html#mocking-modules).

In order to trigger the `onClose` function, you still need to trigger the `onClick` function on `MyModal` component.

Besides, You did not mock the MyModal component correctly. Here is a working example:

`ParentComp.tsx`:

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { MyModal } from './MyModal';

export const ParentComp = () => {
  const [openModal, setOpenModal] = useState(false);
  return (
    <>
      <MyModal showModal={openModal} onClose={() => setOpenModal(false)} />
      <button data-testid="open-modal-button" onClick={() => setOpenModal(true)}>
        Test
      </button>
    </>
  );
};
```

`MyModal.tsx`:

```
import React from 'react';

export const MyModal = ({ showModal, onClose }) => {
  return (
    showModal && (
      <>
        <div>This is a modal</div>
        <button data-testid="close-modal-button" onClick={onClose}>
          Close
        </button>
      </>
    )
  );
};
```

`ParentComp.test.tsx`:

```
import { fireEvent, render } from '@testing-library/react';
import React from 'react';
import { ParentComp } from './ParentComp';

function MockedMyModal({ onClose, showModal }) {
  return (
    showModal && (
      <>
        <div>This is a mocked modal</div>
        <button data-testid="my-modal" onClick={onClose}>
          Close
        </button>
      </>
    )
  );
}

jest.mock('./MyModal', () => {
  return { MyModal: MockedMyModal };
});

describe('65038548', () => {
  afterAll(() => {
    jest.resetAllMocks();
  });
  it('should open the modal', () => {
    const { getByTestId } = render(<ParentComp></ParentComp>);
    const openModalButton = getByTestId('open-modal-button');

    fireEvent.click(openModalButton);
    const myModal = getByTestId('my-modal');

    expect(myModal).toBeDefined();
  });

  it('should close the modal', () => {
    const { getByTestId, queryByText } = render(<ParentComp></ParentComp>);
    const openModalButton = getByTestId('open-modal-button');
    fireEvent.click(openModalButton);

    const closeModalButton = getByTestId('my-modal');
    expect(closeModalButton).toBeDefined();

    fireEvent.click(closeModalButton);

    expect(queryByText('This is a mocked modal')).toBeNull();
  });
});
```

Why use `queryByText` instead of `getByTestId`, see [Asserting elements are not present](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52783201/6463558)

unit test result:

```
 PASS  examples/65038548/ParentComp.test.tsx
  65038548
    ✓ should pass (34 ms)

----------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File            | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
----------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files       |    87.5 |      100 |   66.67 |   85.71 |                   
 ParentComp.tsx |    87.5 |      100 |   66.67 |   85.71 | 8                 
----------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        5.848 s
```

source code: https://github.com/mrdulin/jest-v26-codelab/tree/main/examples/65038548