# How to expect a getByText to be false in react testing library?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I am using Jest and the React testing library to test a component.

I am trying to test a modal and I have a weird issue that I am facing. When I try to get by text the "Modal Title" before firing the event I get en error because the "Modal Title" does not exist in the rendered document. If I try to look for the "Modal Title" after firing the "Open Modal" button it works. But I would like to test as well that the modal does not exist before the triger event. So I decided to expect the "Modal Title" to be false but that doesn't work. So far I have tried the toBe(false), toBeFalsy(), toBeNull() and even tried to see if the lenght is 0 but nothing of the mentioned work. How can I solve this.

```
it('Test Modal', () => {
    
    const { getByText } = render(<TestApp />);
   
    expect(getByText('Modal Title')).toBe(false);
    fireEvent.click(getByText('Open Modal'));
    expect(getByText('Modal Title')).toBeTruthy();
})
```

Comment: `expect(queryByText(...)).not.toBeInDocument()`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you test for the non-existence of an element using jest and react-testing-library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52783144/how-do-you-test-for-the-non-existence-of-an-element-using-jest-and-react-testing)

Comment: @jonrsharpe Nope. Neither one of the two work.

Comment: Please give a [mre] illustrating how precisely they don't work.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can also expect `getByText` to throw an error like so:

```
expect(() => screen.getByText('Modal title')).toThrow();
```

(Note the () => notation at the start.)

Answer (score 3):

You can also use the `queryByText` as this will provide a way to check if the returned value is null and requires less code. The following is one example:

```
const SectionOne = screen.queryByText('Section 1')
expect(SectionOne).toBeNull()
```

Answer (score 1):

Another good approach would be to wait for your open modal, something like:

```
describe('modal component', () => {
  test('should not be rendered', () => {
    render(<TestApp />);
    expect(screen.getByText('Modal Title')).not.toBeInTheDocument();
  });

  test('should be rendered', async () => {
    render(<TestApp />);
    fireEvent.click(screen.getByText('Open Modal'));
    expect(await screen.findByText('Modal Title')).toBeInTheDocument();
  });
});
```

`findBy` methods are a combination of `getBy` queries and `waitFor`.