# How to wait to assert an element never appears in the document?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I want to assert that an element never appears in my document. I know I can do [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52783201/937377):

```js
import '@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect'

it('does not contain element', async () => {
    const { queryByText } = await render(<MyComponent />);
    expect(queryByText('submit')).not.toBeInTheDocument();
});
```

But in my case I need to wait to ensure that the element isn't added after a delay. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There are two ways to do this, both involving `react-testing-library`'s async helper function [`waitFor`](https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-async/#waitfor).

The first and simpler method is to wait until something else happens in your document before checking that the element doesn't exist:

```js
import '@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect'

it('does not contain element', async () => {
    const { getByText, queryByText } = await render(<MyComponent />);

    await waitFor(() => expect(getByText('something_else')).toBeInTheDocument());

    expect(queryByText('submit')).not.toBeInTheDocument();
});
```

You can use the same strategy with any valid Jest assertion:

```js
import '@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect'
import myFunc from './myFunc'

it('does not contain element', async () => {
    const { getByText, queryByText } = await render(<MyComponent />);

    await waitFor(() => expect(myFunc).toBeCalled());

    expect(queryByText('submit')).not.toBeInTheDocument();
});
```

If there isn't any good assertion you can use to wait for the right time to check an element does not exist, you can instead use `waitFor` to repeatedly check that an element does not exist over a period of time. If the element ever does exist before the assertion times out, the test will fail. Otherwise, the test will pass.

```js
import '@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect'

it('does not contain element', async () => {
    const { getByText } = await render(<MyComponent />);

    await expect(async () => {
        await waitFor(
            () => expect(getByText('submit')).toBeInTheDocument();
        );
    }).rejects.toEqual(expect.anything());
});
```

You can adjust the amount of time `waitFor` will keep checking and how frequently it will check using [the `timeout` and `interval` options](https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-async/#waitfor). Do note, though, that since this test waits until `waitFor` times out for the test to pass, increasing the `timeout` option will directly increase the time this test takes to pass.

And here is the helper function I wrote to avoid having to repeat the boilerplate:

```
export async function expectNever(callable: () => unknown): Promise<void> {
    await expect(() => waitFor(callable)).rejects.toEqual(expect.anything());
}
```

Which is then used like so:

```
it('does not contain element', async () => {
  const { getByText } = await render(<MyComponent />);

  await expectNever(() => {
    expect(getByText('submit')).toBeInTheDocument();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 7):

We use plain JavaScript and the expectNever function from @Nathan throws an error:

```
Error: expect(received).rejects.toEqual()
Matcher error: received value must be a promise
```

I modified it to look and feel more like waitFor and this works:

```
const waitForNeverToHappen = async (callable) => {
    await expect(waitFor(callable)).rejects.toEqual(expect.anything())
}
    
await waitForNeverToHappen(() => expect(screen.getByText('submit')).toBeInTheDocument())
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using `waitForElementToBeRemoved` documented here:
https://testing-library.com/docs/guide-disappearance/#waiting-for-disappearance

Comment: This won't work because `waitForElementToBeRemoved` expects the element to be visible first, which is not the OP's case, where the element starts as not visible and must stay like that.

Answer (score 0):

An edge case alternative would be:

```
export const expectNever = async (callable: () => unknown) => {
  try {
    await waitFor(callable);
  } catch {
    return true;
  }
  throw new Error('Occurred what should not occur!');
};
```

and use it like:

```
await expectNever(() => {
    expect(
      screen.queryByText('should not be rendered')
    ).toBeInTheDocument();
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `waitFor()` helper, you can *first* await for another element using `findByText()` and expect to be in the document. Also, it is a better practice to use [`screen`](https://kentcdodds.com/blog/common-mistakes-with-react-testing-library#not-using-screen).

```
  import {render, screen} from '@testing-library/react'
    
  it('does not contain element', async () => {
    render(<MyComponent />);
    const anotherElement = await screen.findByText("another_element");
    const submit = screen.queryByText("submit");
    
    expect(anotherElement).toBeInTheDocument();
    expect(submit).not.toBeInTheDocument();
  });
```